# listening port not allowing the connection

Tags: port, aix

I tried to telnet on port 60120 to a server this way

telnet 60120 hostname

and it gave me the message: telnet: hostname: bad port

but when i login to the server and type netstat -an to check all of the ports, it shows that port 60120 is listening

tcp        0      0  *.60120                *.*                    LISTEN

why is that?

Comment: Less original, but more likely to work: `telnet hostname 60120`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your telnet parameters are inverted. First parameter is the host, second is the port, so to work you will need:

```
telnet hostaname 60120
```